# How to import the text contains comma in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I import the text contains comma.

For e.g.

```
User.create!(name: "lee, patrick", email: "plee@test.com")
```

or

```
Model.create!(name: "22" / 4345-AN9", type: "Monitor")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it easiest in this situation to use the Ruby [`%Q` magic](https://simpleror.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/q-q-w-w-x-r-s/). Anything between `%Q(` and `)` is the string you want, and can contain any number of `'` and `"` without the need to do any escaping.

```
Model.create!(name: %Q(22" / 4345-AN9), type: "Monitor")
```

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to do it for your example:

1. Using `'` to construct the string

   Model.create!(name: '22" / 4345-AN9', type: "Monitor")
2. Using `\` to escape

   Model.create!(name: "22\" / 4345-AN9", type: "Monitor")

Personally, I like the second approach because it can also deal with the situation where you have both `'` and `"` in your string.